# maven sonar plugin use checkstyle rules from pom

Tags: maven, checkstyle, sonarqube

Is there a way to get sonar to use the checkstyle configuration from my pom file? I have the maven checkstyle plugin setup, and I have the maven sonar plugin (version 2.7) setup, but sonar seems to use its default checkstyle configuration. I know I can create a new quality profile and upload the checkstyle file, but I would think that the maven plugin should use the one from the pom. Any help here is appreciated.

thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

It used to be possible from Sonar 1.11 to Sonar 2.2 by using a parameter `sonar.reuseExistingRulesConfiguration`.  It was removed from Sonar 2.3.

- See [SONAR-583](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-583)
- See [SONAR-1706](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-1706)